# Оптимизация запроса (Percona)

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы получить немного помощи(советы там и все такое) с оптимизацией одного запроса. Объемы данных в таблицах от 100к до 800к и сроки выполнения приведенного ниже запроса удручают.
 Собственно вот и он:

```
SET @dm = 3

    SELECT a.specific_unit, a.unit_description, a.inventory_number, a.main_inventory_number, a.link_main_object, a.asset_description, a.asset_type, a.asset_category, a.add_bill, a.amortization_bill, a.expense_bill, a.quantity, a.first_cost, a.amortization, a.current_cost, a.year_amortization, a.month_amortization, a.unplanned_amortization, a.asset_location, a.asset_address, a.cost_center, a.add_date, a.start_date, a.end_date, a.creation_period, a.person, a.asset_key, a.serial_number, a.tag_number, a.lifetime, a.amortization_method, a.amortization_sign, a.correction_sign, a.commitment, a.insurance_contract, a.vhr, a.inventory_number_r11, a.stripping_date, a.ifns, a.okato, a.old_inventory_number, a.start_date_ya, a.end_date_ya, a.document_ya, a.start_tax_date, a.name_doc_gos_reg, a.number_doc_gos_reg, a.main_inventory_level2, a.key_1_type, a.key_2_A_site, a.key_3_B_site, a.key_4_type_A_site, a.key_5_rent, a.key_6_height, a.key_7_mts_k, a.key_8_reserve, b.name AS commentary, c.name AS VIEW, d.spi, @diff_months := (CASE
WHEN a.end_date < '2014-01-01' || a.start_date >= '2014-04-01' THEN 0
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,'2014-04-01') < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2014-01-01', a.end_date) && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,'2014-04-01') < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,a.end_date) && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,'2014-04-01') < @dm THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,'2014-04-01')
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2014-01-01', a.end_date) < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,'2014-04-01') && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2014-01-01', a.end_date) < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.start_date,a.end_date) && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2014-01-01', a.end_date) < @dm THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2014-01-01', a.end_date)
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.start_date, a.end_date) < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.start_date, '2014-04-01') && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.start_date, a.end_date) < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2014-01-01', a.end_date) && TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.start_date, a.end_date) < @dm THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.start_date, a.end_date)
ELSE @dm
END), @total_osv_balance :=
(SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SUM(f.end_balance)
 FROM catalog_osv_gaap_analys AS f
 WHERE f.uniq_number IN(6)
   AND f.inventory_number = a.inventory_number
   AND a.add_bill = f.bill), (CASE
                                  WHEN d.spi = 0 && @total_osv_balance IS NULL || d.spi = 0 && @total_osv_balance = '' THEN 0
                                  WHEN d.spi = 0 && @total_osv_balance <> 0 THEN @total_osv_balance
                                  WHEN @total_osv_balance IS NULL || @total_osv_balance = '' THEN 0 - (a.first_cost / d.spi * @diff_months)
                                  WHEN @total_osv_balance <> 0 THEN @total_osv_balance - (a.first_cost / d.spi * @diff_months)
                              END) AS effect (a.amortization_method - j.amortization_method) AS diff_spi
FROM catalog_gaap_analys AS a
INNER JOIN analys_commentary AS b ON(a.id_analys_commentary = b.id)
INNER JOIN analys_view AS c ON(a.id_view = c.id)
LEFT JOIN analys_spi AS d ON(a.add_bill = d.add_bill)
LEFT JOIN catalog_gaap_analys AS j ON(a.inventory_number = j.inventory_number
                                      AND a.add_bill = j.add_bill)
WHERE a.uniq_number = 4
AND j.uniq_number = 3 LIMIT 0,100000
```

Answer (score 1):

[Используем `EXPLAIN` для оптимизации запросов к `MySQL`](http://mattweb.ru/component/k2/item/65-ispolzuem-explain-dlya-optimizacii-zaprosov-k-mysql)

> Во время выполнения запроса, оптимизатор запросов MySQL пытается ускорить этот процесс. Вы можете увидеть это, если добавите ключевое слово EXPLAIN перед запросом. EXPLAIN – один из самых мощных инструментов, находящийся в вашем распоряжении, для анализа процесса выполнения и оптимизации сложных MySQL-запросов, но, к сожалению, многие разработчики используют его редко. В этой статье я расскажу вам о том, какую информацию выводит EXPLAIN и как, используя ее, можно оптимизировать запросы и структуру базы данных.

Comment: Сорри, надо было упомянуть, что индексы проставлены. Filesort'ов и прочей нечести не обнаружено типы выборки в основном ref или const_ref никаких All и тд.